# Is there a way to output gif animation from blender?

Tags: export, file-format

Is there a way to output an animation or video file in gif format from blender?

If not, what about VSE? Or can I record a screen inside blender?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't a way to export (or import) gif directly.

**GIF is not a supported format** in blender.

You would need to export your images or animation in a different format, and then convert it to GIF using an external application.

For a list of the supported formats [read this](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/image_formats.html?highlight=formats).

To record a screen capture using external software refer to this post in Meta:

[What is the process for creating gifs for questions and answers?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056#1056)